# Consulta con múltiples joins arroja campos en null desde el tercer registro

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema en una multiconsulta: tengo mi sentencia y todo va bien cuando la ejecuto, pero no logro ver el error de por qué me arroja campos en null.

En los campos `plantel` y `tipodepersona` de las tablas `plaalumno` y `cpersona`, hasta el segundo registro va bien pero en el tercero no sé por qué me hace eso.

Dejo la consulta y la imagen:

```
select   mm.idpersona, mm.nombre, mm.appat, mm.apmat, cp.fechainicio, cl.plantel, tp.tipodepersona,
ml.clas, ml.titulo, ml.autor, ml.editorial, ml.fecha, ml.asignatura, ml.isbn, cc.categoria, ca.carrera, cu.cuatrimestre, ct.plantel, mp.periodico, mr.revistas, mo.cantidad

   from  dficha ta 

    inner JOIN mpersona mm ON ta.idprestamo=mm.idpersona 

   inner JOIN dprestamo cp ON ta.idprestamo=cp.idprestamo 

   left JOIN mprestamo mo ON ta.idprestamo=mo.idpresta 

   left JOIN plaalumno cl ON ta.idprestamo=cl.idplaalumno 

      Left JOIN cpersona tp ON ta.idprestamo=tp.idtpersona 
     inner JOIN mlibro ml ON ta.idlibro=ml.idlibro
      inner JOIN ccategoria cc ON ta.idcategoria=cc.idcategoria 
      inner JOIN ccarrera ca ON ta.idcarrera=ca.idcarrera 
    inner JOIN ccuatrimestre cu ON ta.idcuatrimestre=cu.idcuatrimestre 
      inner JOIN cplantel ct ON ta.idplantel=ct.idplantel 
      inner JOIN mperiodico mp ON ta.idperiodico=mp.idperiodico 
      inner JOIN mrevistas mr ON ta.idrevistas=mr.idrevistas
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso ocurre donde usas `LEFT JOIN` ya que te devuelve un `NULL` en aquellas columnas que no tienen datos al juntar las tablas. [Ver documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Comment: Podría ser lo que comenta @A.Cedano, pero podría haber algún otro motivo (aunque tiene pinta de que se trata de eso). no obstante, para saberlo con certeza, el mero modelo de datos no sería suficiente, es en los datos donde puede estar el problema. Mi sugerencia es que vayas restando `inner joins` hasta que no tengas columnas `NULL` y evalúes si realmente no hay datos para que la unión tenga lugar

Comment: Gracias tenian razon los LEFT JOIN me estaban restando resultados ahora ya me funciona :) encerio muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @A. Cedano, esto se debe a que el left join deja como null las columnas que no tienen datos al unir las tablas.

Por otro lado, deberías revisar el orden de los join. La tabla dficha no tiene un idpersona y lo estás relacionando con idprestamo `inner JOIN mpersona mm ON ta.idprestamo=mm.idpersona`.